# $.parseXML return different output in chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, xml-parsing

The below code gives different output in chrome and IE

```
    <script src="\xyz\jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var xml= $("<root/>");


var field=$("<Field/>");
$(field).attr('Name','DateOpened');
$(field).attr('DisplayName','DateOpened');
$(field).attr('Type','DateTime');
$(field).attr('Format','DateOnly');
$(field).attr('Required','FALSE');


var schema= $(field);
xml= $(xml).append(schema);

string= $(xml).prop('outerHTML');

xmlDoc=$.parseXML(string);

</script>

i have also used: 

  if (window.DOMParser)
  {
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(string,"text/xml");
  }
else // Internet Explorer
  {
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(string);
  }
```

In both the cases output for chrome is:

```
<root><field name="DateOpened" displayname="DateOpened" type="DateTime" format="DateOnly" required="required"/></root>
```

and i can access the name attribute like `$(xmlDoc).find(field).attr('name');`// DateOpened

but in IE 8 i am getting the output like

```
   <root><Field name="DateOpened" displayname="DateOpened" type="DateTime" format="DateOnly" required="required"></Field></root>
```

and `$(xmlDoc).find(field).attr('name')// undefined`

and in IE 9 i am getting the output like:

```
<root><field Name="DateOpened" DisplayName="DateOpened" Type="DateTime" Format="DateOnly" Required="required"/></root>
```

and `$(xmlDoc).find(field).attr('name')//undefined`

is it possible to get the output in same format across browsers? so that i can get the field and attributes in consistent way across browsers.